# Builtin speakers work only if i plugin ear phone

Tags: sound, headphones, speakers

By default under "Settings/Sound" I see only: "Headphones - Built-in Audio".

Because of which I am not able to use my laptop speakers.

It is only after I plug in a headphone does the speakers work i.e., under "Settings/Sound" then I see "Speakers Built-in Audio".

But then I am not able to use headphones. So basically, I am never able to use headphones.

== EDIT ==
I have had this issue on Ubuntu 18.04 also. I thought upgrading might fix the issue. But it didn't.

**System**: Dell Latitue E6430

**OS**: Ubuntu 19.04

**OS type**: 64 Bit

Please suggest how could I fix it.